# Assign grading based on available data in R data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, tags, reshape, assign

I have the following two `data.frame`. I want to get the `Grade` from `D1` and Assign to the `Pts` in `D`. Once the operations completes the `D` `data.frame` should have a columns for `Pts`,`Val`, and `Grade` without `C` or `Good` `Grade`.

```
D <- data.frame(Pts= c("A","B","D"), Val = c(3.5,4,5))
D1 = data.frame(Pts = c("A","B","C", "D"), Grade = c("Ugly", "Bad", "Good", "Excellent"))

D$Grade <- D1$Grade
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a join in `data.table` by joining `on` by 'Pts' column and assign (`:=`) the 'Grade' from D1 to D

```
library(data.table)
setDT(D)[D1, Grade := Grade, on = .(Pts)]
```

-output

```
D
   Pts Val     Grade
1:   A 3.5      Ugly
2:   B 4.0       Bad
3:   D 5.0 Excellent
```

---

In `base R`, can do the same with `merge` or more faster `match`

```
D$Grade <- D1$Grade[match(D$Pts, D1$Pts)]
```

---

The line of code

```
D$Grade <- D1$Grade
```

wouldn't work due to multiple reasons

1. The number of rows are not the same
2. Even if the number of rows are same, the 'Pts' in both datasets may not be matching elementwise

Answer (score 3):

You could use a left join:

```r
library(dplyr)

D %>%
  left_join(D1, by="Pts")
```

Comment: Thanks- this will work if you do not have other columns in `D1` `data.frame` and interested in only `Grade`. otherwise, all the columns would be exported to `D`.

Comment: Yeah, but you can either use a select-statement on `D1` first or afterwards on the resulting data.frame.